# Is there any way to speed up or optimize the resolving of Maven dependencies in Spring Boot projects using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am currently a beginner in middleware and services programming using Java Spring Boot framework. I am using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.3 version alongside Spring Boot versions 2.2.5 and 2.3.0 M2 depending on the project I'm working on.

Each time I start a new project, I need specific dependencies such as Spring Boot DevTools, Lombok, Spring Web, Rest Repositories, Spring Data JPA, H2 Database or MySQL Driver, but the thing is, when the project is created and starts resolving Maven dependencies, it takes several hours to complete the process and as shown below, I created my last project since more than 3 and half hours yet it hasn't finished resolving dependencies and it seems to be blocking at "spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar" since more than an hour.

[Spring Boot project I created since more than 3 and half hours still resolving dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OazQJ.png)

I don't know if it's caused by a slow internet connection or IntelliJ's downloading module, but I was wondering if there's a proper way to solve this issue, to resume my questions :

- Is there any way to optimize or speed up the download and resolving of these dependencies ?
- Either way is it possible to download these dependencies separately and include them "manually" to the project ?

Comment: I've never had dependency resolution take more than a few minutes, let alone a few hours. How many dependencies are trying to be resolved, and how large are they?

Comment: In that case, there are actually 5 dependencies to be resolved : 
- Spring Boot DevTools 
- Lombok 
- Spring Web 
- Rest Repositories - Spring Data JPA 
- H2 Database 

No information about their size is shown on IntelliJ, therefore, I don't think they could be that large to take that disproportional amount of time

Comment: I think the problem in your internet connection or network settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to speed up maven artifacts downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974311/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-maven-artifacts-downloading)

Comment: So to update you guys about the situation,, after waiting for 5 hours that day, I just cancelled the process and the very next morning, I tried creating a new project with the same dependencies, miraculously it took me only few seconds, seems like the problem was solved by itself. I believe that the main concern was the internet connection, however I was not the only one in my area having that issue since all my group (~20 persons) had the same case.

Also it seems to be the same case as the topic you sent Ilya, thanks guys for your help !